# Speedup SQL Query with aggregates on DateTime and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I've a large (> 100 million rows) table in my MS SQL database with the following columns:

```
Id int not null,
ObjectId int not null,
Timestamp datetime not null
State int not null
```

`Id` it the primary key of the table (and has a clustered index on it). I added a non clustered index on Timestamp and ObjectId (in this order). There are just around 2000 distinct values in `ObjectId`. I want now perform the following query:

```
SELECT ObjectId, MAX(Timestamp) FROM Table GROUP BY ObjectId
```

It takes something around four seconds, which is too slow for my application. The execution plan says that 97% of the runtime goes to an Index Scan of the non clustered index.

On a copy of the table I created a clustered index on ObjectId and Timestamp. The resulting runtime is same, the execution plan says its doing now a Index Scan of the clustered index.

Is there any other possibility to improve the runtime without splitting the table's data into multiple tables?

Comment: Have you tried an index on ObjectID alone? Although I don't expect it will improve the matter, since the query you're performing needs to touch every row in the database in any case. IMO there will be no improvement possible without upscaling your db server or redesigning your schema (e.g. you could add a second table that keeps the max timestamp for each objectid using a trigger).

Comment: @jeroenh: Yes, I tried this too without any remarkable result-

Comment: Actually we can suppose that do you insert data frequently in this table maybe add a hint in you query : WITH (NOLOCK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose you another answer, add a boolean column LAST and update last true for the ObjectID to false before insert now row for this ObjectID with LAST to true. Create an index on ObjectID and LAST. Query very simple :

```
SELECT ObjectId, Timestamp FROM Table where LAST = true
```

No more group by and fullscan but one more update each for insert.

Comment: Good idea. I tried this and it works really great. The extra UPDATE does not matter that much. It's fast and for me case the runtime of the SELECT statement is much more crucial.

Answer (score 0):

4 seconds in not bad for that kind on work in DB with more 100M rows.
You can archive daily some data in another table to preserve historic. You can archive all data in another table and delete old changing of objects :

```
delete from TABLE where Id in (select t1.Id from Table t1, Table t2  
where t1.ObjectId = t2.ObjectId and t1.Timestamp < t2.Timestamp )
```

Comment: No, this is really bad, 4s are around 3.9s too much :) And my question  explicitly excluded solutions which copy part of the data to another tables.

Comment: So you can buy a better machine or fine tuning MySQL ("key_buffer_size"
in the my.cnf file to increase ram usage of indexes) but you put good indexes. Data in a  database need to be archived you can't think your model can grow up to infinity without performance issue.

Comment: The point is, that the query above has a runtime which depends linearly on the number of rows in the table. And this is suboptimal, does not matter if there are one million or one billion rows in the table. As long the execution plan says it scan the whole table, there is something to improve before starting some archiving techniques.

Comment: It scan the whole INDEX and it is not linear byt by log on the number of rows and that the best perf that can do an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular query, an index on (ObjectId, Timestamp) will be optimal. And there is a chance that (ObjectId, Timestamp DESC) will perform even faster.